# Get list of year ranges from list of years?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get a list of year ranges from a list of years?

Say there is a table like

```
Year
1990
1991
1992
1999
2001
2002
2015
```

Or like

```
Years
1990,1991,1992,1999,2001,2002,2015
```

I am not sure where to start; how can one get the ranges within those years? e.g.

```
1990-1992,1999,2001-2002,2015
```

Comment: Why downvote? If there's something I should avoid doing, it would help to know what it is.

Comment: I got a notification for your most recent comment (because I've commented before), so I guess I can answer why you may get downvotes: you should show that you've at least tried *something* before posting a question.  Just saying you have a problem and hoping someone will just *give you the answer* it is not generally accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is example:

```
SELECT *
INTO #years
FROM (VALUES 
(1990),
(1991),
(1992),
(1999),
(2001),
(2002),
(2015)) AS D(Year)

SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ',' +
    CASE 
        WHEN MIN(Year) = MAX(Year) THEN CAST(MIN(Year) AS VARCHAR(9))
        WHEN MIN(Year) <> MAX(Year) THEN CAST(MIN(Year) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' +CAST(MAX(Year) AS VARCHAR(4))
    END AS [text()]
FROM (
    SELECT Year
        ,Year-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year) AS rowID
    FROM #years) a
GROUP BY rowID
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');
```

The main idea is to find so called islands, which in this case is easy made by using `ROW_NUMBER` in this select:

```
SELECT Year ,Year-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year)
```

Years will be subtracted from row numbers, which will mark same "islands". Meaning, if every next year are increasing by one as row number does, we will get same result number:

```
YEAR  RowNR RESULT  
1999  1     1998  
2000  2     1998  
2015  3     2012
```

This result numbers can be later used for grouping and getting MAX and MIN values.

Comment: I will upvote if you can explain _how_ it works - the `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` distract from the cleverness of the actual query that gets the ranges.

Comment: @DStanley STUFF and XML do not distract here, they are the mechanisms that make this work. This code is generating a comma separated list.

Comment: @DStanley I got what you mean and updated answer, just I am not so good with english or explanation ;)

Comment: @SeanLange I did not read the comma-separated list as a strong requirement (only an example).  A third of the query is to generate the list, which is ugly in my opinion because SQL is not good at it.  The real magic is in the inner query that groups the data into consecutive years.

Answer (score 2):

The technique to get actual ranges is known as [islands and gaps](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/). And to get values aggregated in one row you can use different techniques, but here's simple one with accumulating data in the variable will work fine.

```
declare @temp table (y int)
declare @res nvarchar(max)

insert into @temp (y)
values
    (1990),
    (1991),
    (1992),
    (1999),
    (2001),
    (2002),
    (2015)

;with cte_rn as (
    select
        row_number() over(order by y) as rn, y
    from @temp
), cte_rng as (
    select
        case
            when count(*) = 1 then cast(min(y) as nvarchar(max))
            else cast(min(y) as nvarchar(max)) + '-' + cast(max(y) as nvarchar(max))
        end as rng
    from cte_rn
    group by y - rn
)
select @res = isnull(@res + ', ', '') + rng
from cte_rng
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2262)</kbd>**